# Javascript - Para que serve uma function dentro de parênteses?

Tags: javascript

Um dia desses eu vi um códigos em **javascript** e fiquei me perguntando o porquê de usar **parênteses** para fechar uma function:

```
(function(){

});
```

Tipo esse **código** acima. Agradeço qualquer explicação.

Comment: O nome disso é `IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression)`. Isso indica que assim que o JavaScript criar a função, ela será executada. `(function(){
/* Code */
})();`

Comment: Hmm interessante, obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Veja se os links no box amarelo lá em cima te esclarecem. Senão, avise aqui.